# Consulta con alert de JQuery-Confirm en Javascript

Tags: javascript

*Este es el sitio desde el cual ocupo los alerts personalizados:
[https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/_)*

Tengo un alert personalizado el cual me muestra un mensaje cada vez que alguna condición no se cumpla.

Este es el código:

```js
function ValidaFecha(e){

  var fecha1 = new Date(desde.value);
  var fecha2 = new Date(hasta.value);
  var hoy = new Date();
  
  if (fecha2 < fecha1) {

    
    alert('La fecha final no puede ser menor que la fecha final.'); 
    return false;
  
  }else if(fecha1 < hoy){
    alert('La fecha escogida no puede ser menor que la fecha actual');
    document.getElementById('desde').focus();
    return false;
  
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
.option2{
  
  position: relative;
  left: 0cm;
  width: 25%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  height: 6mm;
  outline-style: none;
}
.option{
  
  width: 25%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  height: 6mm;
  outline-style: none;
}
.body{
  
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';

}
.form-control{
   border-style: solid;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-width: 1px;
   padding-left: 1mm;
   outline-style: none;
}
.btn{
 
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 color: white;
 width: 25%;
 height: 7mm;
 font-size: 11pt;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 outline-style: none;
}
.btn:hover{
 
 transform: scale(0.9);
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<form name="horario" id="horario" action="#">
<div class="body">
  <label>SELECCIONE UN RANGO DE FECHAS</label>
  <br><br>
  <span>Inicio:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="desde"  id="desde" required="required" />&nbsp;
   <span>Termino:</span>
   <input type="date" class="form-control" name="hasta" id="hasta" required="required"/>
<br><br>
<label>SELECCIONE UN HORARIO</label>
<br><br>
<span>Hora comienzo:</span>
<select name="sel" id="options1" required="required" class="option">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<span>Hora termino:</span>
<select name="sel2" id="options2" required="required" class="option2">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
    <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" onclick="return ValidaFecha(event)" class="btn">
</div>
</form>
```

Para este ejemplo me valida que la fecha escogida final no sea menor que la fecha inicial. Solo que lo hice más simple, originalmente lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidaFecha(e){

    var fecha1 = new Date(desde.value);
    var fecha2 = new Date(hasta.value);

    if (fecha2 < fecha1) {

        $('#hasta').focus();

          $.alert({
            title: ''+'<nav style=" background: #478573; color:white; width: 15cm; height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top: 2.5mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Atención!</nav>',
            content: ''+' <p style= "color: black; font-weight: 500;" >La fecha de término no puede ser menor que la fecha inicial.</p>',

        });

        return false;
      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Quisiera saber como puedo mostrar la fecha, sé que se puede si concateno variables, de momento lo hice de esta manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidaFecha(e){

      var fecha1 = new Date(desde.value);
      var fecha2 = new Date(hasta.value);

      var hoy = new Date();
      var Anio = hoy.getFullYear();

      var months = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];

      var days = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];

      var Mes = months[hoy.getMonth()];
      var Dia = days[hoy.getDate()];
      var dia_n = hoy.getDate();

      if(fecha1 < hoy){

        $('#desde').focus();

          $.alert({
            title: ''+'<nav style=" background: #478573; color:white; width: 15cm; height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top: 2.5mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Atencion!</nav>',
            content: ''+' <p style= "color: black; font-weight: 500;" >La fecha de escogida no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.<br><br>Actualmente estamos a: </p>'+Dia+' '+dia_n+' '+'de'+' '+Mes+' '+'del'+' '+Anio,

        });

        return false;

      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
  }
</script>
```

Pero lo que quiero es que aparezca dentro del párrafo, dentro de la etiqueta **`<p></p>`** en el **`content:`** porque como lo hice en un principio me aparece con un doble espaciado *`(no lo digo por los <br> ya que eso aplica dentro del <p> sin los <br> sigue el doble espacio);`* y sin el estilo que le establecí al párrafo, ¿Se puede lograr?

Lo otro es que cuando valido que la fecha ingresada no sea menor que la actual, **aunque ingrese la actual no pasa** el formulario, como si al colocar esto **`if(fecha1 < hoy)...`** en el **`if`** este signo **`<`** lo tomara como si fuese esto **`<=`**. ¿Como se puede arreglar también esto último?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colega, tu error es simplemente que estas cerrando el tag `<p>` y *DESPUÉS* muestras la fecha actual... sólo debes cambiar esto

```
content: ''+' <p style= "color: black; font-weight: 500;" >La fecha de escogida no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.<br><br>Actualmente estamos a: </p>'+Dia+' '+dia_n+' '+'de'+' '+Mes+' '+'del'+' '+Anio,
```

por esto

```
content: `<p style="color:black;font-weight: 500;">La fecha de escogida no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.<br><br>Actualmente estamos a: ${Dia} ${dia_n} de ${Mes} del ${Anio}</p>'
```

Nos comentas :)

PD: Como consejo, te sugiero fuertemente utilizar la librería **[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)**, la cual maneja fechas de una manera extraordinariamente fácil (incluidas validaciones que podrías necesitar)

Comment: Ya veo era eso, había que jugar con las comillas. Lo probé y funciona.Gracias colega.

Comment: Si quieres puedes crear otra pregunta con el problema y como comunidad te ayudamos a resolverlo :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar **plantillas de cadena de texto**(template string)

Por ejemplo si yo tengo un texto y necesito a ese texto concatenar una variable.

```js
let name = "Test"
let text = `Hola ${name}`
console.log(text)
```

En tu caso seria algo  parecido a esto.

```js
let Dia = "Martes"
let dia_n = 11
let Mes = "Noviembre"
let Anio = 2018

let content = `<p style= "color: black; font-weight: 500;" >La fecha de escogida no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.<br><br>Actualmente estamos a: ${Dia} ${dia_n} de ${Mes} del  ${Anio}</p>`

console.log(content)
```

Respecto a los estilos el color negro del párrafo ya lo tiene por defecto.

Comment: Amigo, luego de revisarlo, lo adapte a mi codigo, pero no funciona en el cuerpo del alert muestra esto: ...estamos a: ${Anio} cuando debería mostrar 2018

Comment: Mira [Aqui](https://jsbin.com/cowevemiyo/edit?html,js,output) y comprueba que este bien